# strategy to follow when a file is relevant to two different commits

Tags: git, version-control

I have a file that I am about to commit to my repo, but it is relevant to two different commits.

It is a PHP that produces the class name that some css files use. So I want to commit all of them at the same time, but if I do that, I won't have a chance to specify the bugfix I made in the PHP file that outputs the class names.

On the other hand, if I do two separated commits so I can specify all the history properly for each commit, if in the future I checkout the commit where I made changes to the CSS, that commit won't work as the correct PHP won't be available, so I (or any other developer) will have to be go two steps back (one for the css files, another for the php bugfixed) in the branch for the whole thing to work.

What is the most adequate strategy in this scenario?

Comment: This isn't clear.  Are you saying you wrote a file to fix two bugs simultaneously?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The PHP was the only one with a bug, and was producing wrong CSS class names that were correct in the CSS files. I had to fix the PHP and after that, I could see the CSS properly applied. Also in parallel I made changes to the CSS files to improve the layout appearance. At that point is when I have to do the commit and when my previously described doubt appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it sounds like you want to `squash` those commits together so that they are merged as one commit.  It doesn't sound like it's ideal, but with a `squash` you can keep the separate commit message history for each commit being squashed, but it will be in one commit.

Here is some [awesome documentation](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html) on using `git rebase -i` which can perform `squash`.

Comment: Many thanks for the help CDub and the squashing idea. Are you then saying that it is better to do a combined commit of both the bugfixed PHP and the more complete CSS files altogether with a verbose commit message?

Comment: Bingo. :)  This way you have one commit for everything that relies on other changes -- if you back out one, you back out them all.

Comment: great. So then, is it better to do two commits and then rebase, or do only one if I can? I am thinking about a commit message like this "implemented box number five (CSS) and fixed bug in the class name generated by the PHP" or is it better to do in a commit #1 (implemented box number five (CSS)) and #2 (fixed bug in the class name generated by the PHP) and then squash them?

Comment: Personally, I'd aim to do the fewest commits that I could. So if you can do just one, I'd do that.  Squashing commits should only be done if absolutely necessary.

Comment: Ok cool! That's what I wanted to know. I have clicked as accepted answer. Cheers